# Rotation Matrix Applied to Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let's say I have the standard rotational matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\y' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta ) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

If I have function $y=f(x)$ how can I apply this matrix to the coordinate plane to get a rotation? Because, replace the $x$ and $y$ values for $f(x)$ with $x'$ and $y'$, I end up getting a wrong answer (i.e. $y'=f(x')$ is wrong, where $x'=x\cos(\theta ) -y\sin(\theta)$ and $y'=x\sin(\theta ) +y\cos(\theta)$). Simply by luck, I found that $[x\sin(\theta ) -y\cos(\theta)=f(x\sin(\theta ) +y\cos(\theta))]$ is the correct transformation, but I have no idea why this works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind in general the result isn't of the form $y^\prime=g(x^\prime)$.

Comment: What would be the general result then?

Comment: Invert the rotation matrix to write $x,\,y$ in terms of $x^\prime,\,y^\prime,\,\theta$, then substitute in $y-f(x) =0$ to get a result of the form $h_\theta(x^\prime,\,y^\prime)=0$.